# HTML5 Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, forms

I am trying to get a form to submit an action to an ip address without open the ip address.

So, when I hit the submit button I want it to send the post command to the ip (in this case 192.168.0.1) and just refresh the current page.

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<form method="POST" action="http://192.168.0.1/">
<input type="submit" name="parser" value="thisguy"/>
</form>
</div>
```

My script that runs on submit:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/liubs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
        var that = $(this),
            url = that.attr('action'),
            method = that.attr('method'),
            data - {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function() {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();
            data[name] = value;

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: method:,
                data: data,
                success: function(response) {}

            });

        });

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Right now it submits the post and tries to open 192.168.0.1 as a webpage. Can someone help me out either by providing code with an explanation or pointing me to the command?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Theres a type-o in your code at  "type: method:," an extra colon

Comment: Why u use a form when you send the request via ajax ?

Comment: Also what’s the deal with that `data - {}` line? Have you used [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) before asking this question?

Comment: If you add preventdefault() into ur ajax function the page wont/need refreshing. If you do want the page to refresh you could just write location =location after the ajax req has completed.

Comment: @Xufox I have not and I am running the code through it now! Thank you!

Comment: @Nimmi I was told to do that. Can you explain? I am using the form now to capture the data from a user and submit it. I am planning on having more forms for submissions.

Comment: @JeremiahLandi you can just use a div to wrap all the input fields and then if u press a button call a function and this function gets the value (by id or what ever). Then you can continue with ajax;

Comment: @JeremiahLandi no problem m8 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action (using [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/))

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default submit action (that is, redirecting)
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        method = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function() {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();
        data[name] = value;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method:,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {}

        });

    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I think that `return false` would be enough.

Comment: @Flash `preventDefault()` and `return false` are different — see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: @StephenP Should it be event.preventDefault(); or e.preventDefault();?

Comment: @Jeremiah `preventDefault()` is a method on the event object. If your event parameter name is ***e*** then you would indeed invoke it as `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @StephenP in jQuery documentation, they say that return false is enough... I know that preventDefault() is totally different thing... but... `submit` event is a bit... "virtual".

Comment: @Flash in a jQuery context `return false` is actually more "severe" than preventDefault() since it also causes `e.stopPropagation()`, not only preventing the default handling but preventing further event propagation - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/17300) to the question I linked earlier. In that sense I would say that "preventDefault() would be enough" and return false would be overkill. The questions to ask yourself before choosing are - do you want to stop other attached handlers from running? and do you want to stop the event bubbling?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can refresh the page after the POST is done in `success` method

```
success: function(response) {
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Also do not forget to disable the form default behavior with

```
 $('form.ajax').on('submit', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   .
   .
 });
```

See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I have done correction to your code.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = $(this),
            url = that.attr('action'),
            method = that.attr('method'),
            data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function() {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();
            data[name] = value;

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: method,
                data: data,
                success: function(response) {}

            });

        });

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @TotalDotoNeto Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To enable debugging, you should wrap the whole submit handler in a try/catch because without it, errors will cause the default handler to submit the form, masking the errors. After the try/catch you can return false, so the page stays put.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/liubs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
        try {
            var that = $(this),
                url = that.attr('action'),
                method = that.attr('method'),
                data - {};

            that.find('[name]').each(function() {
                var that = $(this),
                    name = that.attr('name'),
                    value = that.val();
                data[name] = value;

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: method:,
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response) {}

                });

            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log( 'submit handler error: ' + err.message );
        }

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think starting the handler with `e.preventDefault()` might be an alternative if you want to avoid using try/catch.  I've never tried that.

Answer (score 0):

You just had couple of typo, like `-` instead of `=` and extra `:`, else your code is fine, below is working example.

```js
$(function(){
    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
        var that = $(this),
            url = that.attr('action'),
            method = that.attr('method'),
            data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function() {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();
            data[name] = value;

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: method,
                data: data,
                success: function(response) {
                 alert('posted')
                }

            });

        });

        return false;
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<form method="POST" action="http://192.168.0.1/" class="ajax">
<input type="submit" name="parser" value="thisguy"/>
</form>
</div>
My script that runs on submit:
```